# Quiz app that cycles through the divs on the click of the next button

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom

I am new to javascript and am working on a quiz project. I am trying to loop through the divs so that they show up one by one on the click of the next button. For some reason it skips the second div.

```
<div id='question-one' class='questions active-question'></div>
<div id='question-two' class='questions active-question'></div> 
<div id='question-three' class='questions active-question'></div>
```

```
const nextButton = document.getElementById('myButton');
        
        nextButton.addEventListener('click', setNextQuestion);

        function setNextQuestion() {

            var isNowTheActiveQuestion = document.getElementsByClassName('questions');

            for (activeQuestion of isNowTheActiveQuestion) {
                activeQuestion.classList.remove('active-question');
            } 
            activeQuestion.classList.add('active-question');   
        }
```

Comment: Hi Trell, can you show your HTML so that we have a context of how you are using your JS?

Comment: it wouldn't let me add the full html, kept giving me problems. Inside each questions div, I have an h4, p and another div that's a form with inputs.

Comment: Why are you adding the class again after the for? That line doesn't make much sense to me, `activeQuestion` souldn't be used outside the loop. Try removing it.

Comment: I need to only show one question at a time, and have the question switch every time the next button is hit.

Comment: I can’t see anywhere in the code you have shown which moves to the next question. You just pick up the last one every time, hence with only three questions it looks as though it’s just skipping the second. If there were four it would skip two and three. Have a close look at what the code is actually doing.

Comment: And why do all the questions start off as being active?

Comment: yeah, i figured it out thanks. needed a for loop with an index.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to give "active-question" class for all  items. You should give just what item you want to see first.

```
 <div id='question-one' class='questions active-question'></div>
  <div id='question-two' class='questions'></div> 
  <div id='question-three' class='questions'></div>
```

Now come to the Js code

```
const nextButton = document.getElementById('myButton');

    nextButton.addEventListener('click', setNextQuestion);

    let count = 1;
    function setNextQuestion() {
        const isNowTheActiveQuestion = document.getElementsByClassName('questions');
        for(let i = 0; i < isNowTheActiveQuestion.length; i++){
          isNowTheActiveQuestion[i].classList.remove('active-question');
        };
        if(count > isNowTheActiveQuestion.length - 1){
          count = 0;
        };
        isNowTheActiveQuestion[count++].classList.add('active-question');
    };
```